Flow deployment gack Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1045887962-82268 (39678550)
Above error I receive when deploying autolaunched flow to scratch org created from snapshot. Everything deploys correctly to scratch org created in traditional way. Even when source for snapshot is the source org that has this flow deployed correctly few minutes ago, then the one coming from snapshot experience this issue. Seems like during creation process using snapshot is messing up somehow the flow metadata, or any of dependencies, which I cant figure out.
Gack:
An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1045887962-82268 (39678550)

We as customers can't really work with the gack number, you'd need to contact actual Salesforce support. However, we can try and help diagnose the issue. Is it possible that your sandbox is on summer and production is on spring making a mismatch of API level and then your flow uses the latest API version?

Hi Dan, ofc, looking on many fronts for support. Yes, my sandbox is on Summer 24, and both scratch orgs (Source and Snap) are on summer release too.

Based on above gack seem like it might be due to some cache issue, can you log a case with support
